# Enum type Warning in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, enums, warnings

I am writing a code on lpc1788 ARM Cortex M3. I came across a strange warning when I tried to configure the ports as GPIO.
Despite of the warning, the code works absolutely fine, but to learn why this warning come, I am putting forward this post here.
Following is the code that I have written.

```
static uint32_t * PIN_GetPointer(uint8_t portnum, uint8_t pinnum)  
{  
    uint32_t *pPIN = NULL;  
    pPIN = (uint32_t *)(LPC_IOCON_BASE + ((portnum * 32 + pinnum)*sizeof(uint32_t)));  
    return pPIN;  
}    

void PINSEL_SetPinMode ( uint8_t portnum, uint8_t pinnum, PinSel_BasicMode modenum)  
{  
    uint32_t *pPIN = NULL;  
    pPIN = PIN_GetPointer(portnum, pinnum);  
    *(uint32_t *)pPIN &= ~(3<<3);    //Clear function bits  
    *(uint32_t *)pPIN |= (uint32_t)(modenum<<3);  
}  

int main(void)  
{  
    PINSEL_SetPinMode(1,15,0);  //this gave a warning: enumerated type mixed with another type  
    PINSEL_SetPinMode(1,18,PINSEL_BASICMODE_NPLU_NPDN);    //this doesnt give any warning  

   /* Following is the enum present in a GPIO related header file, putting it here in comments so that   
       those who are going through this post, can see the enum  

            typedef enum
            {
                PINSEL_BASICMODE_NPLU_NPDN  = 0, // Neither Pull up nor pull down        
                PINSEL_BASICMODE_PULLDOWN,       // Pull-down enabled
                PINSEL_BASICMODE_PULLUP,         // Pull-up enabled (default)         
                PINSEL_BASICMODE_REPEATER        // Repeater mode          
            }PinSel_BasicMode;        
   */

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: what does exactly the warning say?

Comment: I have mentioned the warning in code itself Sir, in main() line 3. It says:  188D - enumerated type mixed with another type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `int` type where `enum PinSel_BasicMode` type is required. While enums and ints are usually interchangeable, they are different types.

Value `0` is not an enum value. `PINSEL_BASICMODE_NPLU_NPDN` is. It is only `0` through definition.

Should the enum declaration change and `PINSEL_BASICMODE_NPLU_NPDN` was equal to 1, your code would be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** You're passing an `int` where a `enum` value is expected. So either, cast it to the correct enum, or better: use the correct `enum` value directly:

```
PINSEL_SetPinMode(1, 15, (PinSel_BasicMode)0);
PINSEL_SetPinMode(1, 15, PINSEL_BASICMODE_NPLU_NPDN);
```

**2.** You're using the bit shift operator on a `enum` value. I think you need to cast before and after the bit shift to make the compiler happy:

```
void PINSEL_SetPinMode ( uint8_t portnum, uint8_t pinnum, PinSel_BasicMode modenum)  
{  
    uint32_t *pPIN = NULL;  
    pPIN = PIN_GetPointer(portnum, pinnum);  
    *pPIN &= ~(3<<3);    //Clear function bits  
    *pPIN |= (uint32_t)((uint32_t)modenum << 3);
}
```

Before: because you want to shift an integer value instead of the `enum` value.

After: because the output type of a shift operation is not necessarily the same as the input type.

Comment: This is actually an answer to a different question... :)

Comment: @Dariusz: thanks for pointing that out, idd he seemed to have 2 issues with the code. I have updated my answer and you already got my upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Enums are defined type and hence here warning is of incomatible type with int, so you can typecast to avoid warning.

But as here 0 is defined for your enum so it doesnot cause your code to give wrong result.

Hope it helps.....